# Modal Confirmation Custom Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I've put together a script which allows a user to view their uploaded images in a gallery format as shown [here](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/gallerytest.php#/0).

Using the jQuery demo [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-confirmation.html), I'm now trying to implement a custom dialog box to appear when the user selects a image to be deleted. I already have the error message written as shown in the extract below:

```
Galleria.ready(function() {
    this.$('thumblink').click();

    $(".galleria-image").append("<span class='btn-delete'></span>");  
    $(".btn-delete").live("click", function() {
        var img = $(this).closest(".galleria-image").find("img");      
        alert('Deleting image... ' + $(img).attr("src"));     
        return false; 
    }); 
});
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't find a way to create the `div` around it which is necessary for the dialog box. I'm relatively new to Javascript, so perhaps this is a really basic error, but I just wondered whether someone could have a look at this please and let me know where I've gone wrong?

Many thanks and regards

Comment: Check new code, it create a custom dialog box,i hope it be useful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this:

```
$('<div>').html('Deleting image... ' + $(img).attr("src")).dialog({autoOpen:true});
```

--

i think this one work for you:

```
Galleria.ready(function() {
    this.$('thumblink').click();

    $(".galleria-image").append("<span class='btn-delete'></span>");  
    $(".btn-delete").live("click", function() {
        var img = $(this).closest(".galleria-image").find("img");      

// Dialog
var dialog=$('<div>').addClass('cDialog').html('Deleting image... ' + $(img).attr("src")).appendTo('#galleria').hide().fadeIn();

// On Success Delete You Can Do
// dialog.text('Deleted').delay(1000).remove();
// or

// dialog.remove();

        return false; 
    }); 
});
```

CSS:

```
#galleria{
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}

.cDialog{
width:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
padding:13px;
background-color:#F2F2F2;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Hi @MR.OK, many thanks for taking the time to help. This could very well be me that has done something wrong, but if I change this `alert('Deleting image... ' + $(img).attr("src")); return false; });` to the line you suggest, it throws the rest of my code out which creates the 'thumbnail gallery'. Kind regards

Comment: Hi @MR.OK I really appreciate all the time you're spending on this. The banner is a great idea and some clever coding, but I really need a dialog box, so that the user can select ok to delete the image or cancel if they've changed their mind.Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM so for that you must include jQueryUI into your project, or you can do that with `confirm('do you want delete?')`

Comment: many thanks, agaion for the all the help you're providing. I have included the jQueryUI, but unfortunately I'm still having the problems with the thumbnail gallery, i.e. it no longer opens on page load. I've updated the 'gallery' page in my original post to reflect this. Have you any ideas please? Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

want a div around the image?

You can easily wrap a div around the image.

```
  <div id="inner">Hello/>
```

Try using the below code:

```
$('#inner').wrap('<div class="new" />');
```

The output would be as below:

```
<div class="new">
    <div id="inner">Hello</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi @kiran Tej, thank you for taking the time to help. I'm not too sure whether the `div` needs to be around the image. But for the `Modal Confirmation` dialog box to work, there needs to be a div with a matching id allocated to it. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

first of all you must set you image delete link correctly; 
 Like:

`<a title="delete img.jpg" href="delete.php?img={$id}"><span class="btn-delete"></span></a>`

then:

```
Galleria.ready(function() {
    this.$('thumblink').click();

    $(".galleria-image").append("<span class='btn-delete'></span>");  
    $(".btn-delete").parent().live("click", function() {
        var link = this.href;  // Get Image delete link    

        var dialog = $("<div>").text("Are you want to " + this.title + " ?");
        dialog.dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Delete all items": function() {
                    var result = $.get(link + "&ajax=1"); // you must echo "YES" with php if success of "NO" if false
                    if(result == "YES"){
                       // Show 
                       // alert('Deleted');
                    } else {
                        // Fail
                        // Try Again

                    }
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });

        return false; 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: sincere thanks for this. I've added this to my code but unfortunately I receive the following error:  `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: )` an it seems to suggest that `jquery-1.7.2.min.js` is the cause, although I've been using this link without any problems. I'm not sure whether I've implemented the code correctly. I've updated my test script. Could you possibly please have a look at it, just to make sure I've added correctly? Kind regards